# Type.GetType fails even though class exists

Tags: vb.net, system.reflection

I have a text file that contains different types of data on each row. I'm trying to read the file and create a different (sub)class instance for each one. So I did...

```
Dim t As Type = Type.GetType("DtaRow")
```

And this returns Nothing. This is odd, because the very next bit of code in the same file/namespace/everything is...

```
Public Class DtaRow...
```

In fact, the code I'm typing formerly just called it's New method without problem. So maybe I need to do this...

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("DtaRow")
```

Nope, that's Nothing as well. So then I followed some instructions I found here about looping over the Assemblies to look in all of them... no luck there either. So then I try looking for "Int32" and a bunch of others, phail.

Can someone tell me the obvious thing I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: from MSDN: `If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.`  so `Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.DtaRow")` should work.  The same for the second method: `The name parameter includes the namespace but not the assembly. `

Comment: Is there a way to find/iterate-over the namespace programmatically? The classes are designed to span spaces in an extension-like manner, this method is in a base class and might be called from any number of other places yet need to return classes in those spaces.

Comment: I dont quite follow, but to *find* the current namespace: `Me.GetType.Namespace` for a class or form.  Or use an empty `NameSpaceFinder` class, create one and use it in place of `Me`.  Now you can prepend it to the text name.  That has some limits, so I might create a Dictionary of class to NameSpace.ClassName lookups; that shoud be faster than Reflection to find stuff.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is the link to the MSDN page @Plutonix referenced, if you want to read up further.

Comment: Ahhh, @Plutonix, that was the trick I was missing. In retrospect why the API doesn't do this automatically is a bit of a mystery, but c'est la vie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a single `Assembly` can have multiple `Namespaces` and a type of the same name *can* exist in more that one NameSpace, you have to qualify the type name with the Namespace.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

```
' should work
myT = Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.DtaRow")
' similarly:
myT = Type.GetType("System.Int32")
```

The NameSpace is integral to the Type name and NET does much the same:

```
Dim a As New Animal
myT = a.GetType()
Console.WriteLine(myT.ToString())
' => MyApplication1.Animal
```

If the code is in a form or class in the same namespace, `Me.GetType.Namespace` will get you the string name you can prepend; or you can use a dummy class.  However, the mention of using the code in/as an extension might make that problematic.  First `Me` will not be legal and using a dummy type will report the `NameSpace` for the dummy object.

If **there is only one NameSpace** to deal with, just use a variable and set it once:

```
Friend myNameSpace As String
  ...
' elsewhere something like a MainForm sets it:
myNameSpace - Me.GetType().NameSpace & "."
```

Then, just prepend that to the type names you load.

For **more than one involved NameSpace**, I'd use a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` using the type name as the key and NameSpace qualified string as the value:

```
myTypeName.Add("DtaRow", "FooNameSpace.DtaRow")
myTypeName.Add("Animal", "CircusActs.Animal")
```